# How can I wait the while loop?

Tags: objective-c, while-loop, delay

Here is my code:

```
float interval = 0.03;

while (interval > 0.005) {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"%f", interval);
    interval = interval - 0.005;
}
```

How can I make the while loop to wait an specific amount of time after every loop? I've been searching thing like sleep or performSelector:withObject:afterDelay but neither they don't work nor I don't know how to use them... Some help please?

Comment: `sleep`? `usleep`? `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`? Take your pick.

Comment: @HinataHyuga exactly what is that comment supposed to be doing there? I fail to see how it's relevant.

Comment: sleep, usleep and the other does not work because it pauses all my app until the time is finished... i don't want that to happen, I want to to wait 5 sec after decreasing the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive structure:

```
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [self recursiveMethode:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.3]];

}

-(void)onTimer
{
    NSLog(@"timer");
}


-(void)recursiveMethode:(NSNumber *)interval
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval.doubleValue target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"%f", interval.doubleValue);
    double delay = 1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(recursiveMethode:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval.doubleValue - 0.05] afterDelay:delay];
}
```

Comment: That function isn't recursive, it's repetitious.

Comment: Repetitous funktions are a special recursive funktions.